# Hashing: what is chaining within table (open addressing) using a stack

Tags: java, hash

I have a question that is likely basic but I cannot find the clear explanation. I'm trying to clarify the concept.

What exactly is chaining within a table (using open addressing) and using a stack to keep track of free space. I can't quite seem to find clarification as to what chaining within the table is. Thanks or if there's a link that covers it that would be sufficient. This does not involve linear probing or quadratic probing.

Thank you.

Addendum: chaining within a table is? (not using linear probing or quadratic probing here)

Comment: Where did you hear about this? Can you provide a link or reference?

Comment: The question is for a problem set (I'm not asking for code here). I'm trying to clarify exactly what we're being asked to accomplish.

Comment: Open chaining (addressing) is easy enough to describe, though I don't know what you mean regarding the stack. Note that open addressing doesn't work very well in a managed-memory language like Java, and the standard `HashMap` implementation uses closed addressing.

Comment: Regarding chaining generally, it describes the problem of what to do when you have keys whose hashes collide. [Wikipedia has a good overview.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)

Comment: @CSnovice- My question is what's meant by using a stack to track free space. I've studied data structures extensively and never come across this before, so I was wondering if you could provide a link to where this is being described so I could look over it and give an answer.

Comment: Essentially, the concept is: open addressing with chaining within a table. Then a stack is to be used to keep track of free space. (not linear probing or quadratic probing)

Comment: I don't have a link; just the question to clarify, essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the case, but a stack may be used to track slots that are "freed". It means that for each hash function value there's a stack that contains all free slots. When you need to find additional slot to insert value to - you just get it from the stack.

It's probably used to prevent fragmentation and thus longer lookups for available slots.

Initially the stack will point to the first slot, but when data gets added and deleted, freed slots will be pushed to the stack.

Comment: The stack is being used here to keep track of free memory. I think from some language I'm looking at that the stack tracks the number of elements to be placed into the table.

Comment: What do you mean by "the stack tracks the number of elements to be placed into the table"? I suppose it's exactly for tracking free entries within entries for each hash value.

Comment: Right the free stack has the elements to be placed into the table. The program pops the stack as each element is placed into the table.

Comment: ... and pushes the next free element (in case the stack contains ranges - for efficiency)

Comment: What exactly is meant by "chaining within a table" (not using linear probing or quadratic probing"? thanks

Comment: As I have no additional information about the question, it can be that the hash value corresponds to a range within the table and you use the stack to keep track of open slots within this range. But It's just a guess.
So for example you get h(key) = 5000-10000. This range has a stack associated with, which initially holds the whole range (5000..10000). You pop the range, place your value at 5000 position and push the "new free range" - 5001-10000 to the stack and so on. Eventually when a slot is freed - the stack will have 2 elements on it (the range is splitted)

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking carefully through a variety of references and couldn't see a use of a stack in a hash anywhere. If you have a ref on chaining with a table that would be much appreciated. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_chain describes chaining as multiple application of hash function(s). Don't know what exactly is understood by a table in your case.